# Command to create a file owned by another user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, root

I created a directory `test` owned by the `root` user, and then I created a file called `F1` inside  `test` , now I need to create a file called `T5` inside `test` but by a user called `student`

What is the command to do that?

This what I did:

```
root@mylamp:/# mkdir test
root@mylamp:/# touch F1
```

Now I need to access `test` by the user `student` to create `F5`

```
student@mylamp:/test$
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, I think you should edit your question and make it more readable.
What you are looking for are either chmod, chown or setfacl.

**a) chmod**

You can modify the permissions for the directory "test" with chmod in order to give another user access to it.

For instance, you could do

```
chmod 777 test
```

Now everyone has write access to this directory, also your student user. Please be aware that you are giving away more permissions than you might like.

**b) chown**

Put the user student into a group and do

```
chown root:studentgroup test
```

Afterwards make sure that groups may write into that directory:

```
chmod 774 test
```

**c) setfacl**

Another approach could be to use ACLs. ACLs are made for a more complex permissions management. You can use setfacl to manage the permissions for a directory or file.
For example you can run the following command:

```
setfacl -m u:student:rwx test
```

This command ensures that the user student has read, write and execute permissions on test.
Please note that this only works when the underlying file system was mounted with ACL support (see /etc/fstab).